# Ignore specific lines of inserted file using \input{}

Tags: xetex

I do documentation on a large scale with somewhat strict standardization, meaning most of the preamble should be inserterd from **one place**. This poses difficulties when wanting to change say 3 lines of the preamble.

Currently I have

```
input{../../company\ preamble.tex}
```

But I need to ignore the three first lines of this preamble and use something else instead, but I don't know how to approach this. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: it depends what's in the file. you may be able to undo by redefining things afterwards rather than ignoring the first lines, or you could usually real it line by line with `\read` instead of `\input` and skip three lines. Or simplest just make teh script that is running latex also copy the file and delete three lines.

Comment: or if you have write access to the file make it start `\ifzzz` and have `\fi` on line 4, then do `\zzzfalse` before input.